# How do i create a metadataId for a custom class derived from OrganizationRequest?

Tags: c#, dynamics-crm-2011

I have created a custom  retrieve entity response class for crm2011 so as to serialize the class. The entity response class is derived from ***OrganizationRequest*** class. Its as shown below:

```
public partial class RetrieveEntityRequest : OrganizationRequest
{

    public RetrieveEntityRequest()
    {

    }
    private System.Guid metadataIdField;
    public System.Guid MetadataId
    {
        get
        {
            return this.metadataIdField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.metadataIdField = value;
        }
    }

    public EntityFilters EntityFilters { get; set; }
    public string LogicalName { get; set; }
    public bool RetrieveAsIfPublished { get; set; }
}
```

Now when i run  the code shown below

```
using (OrganizationServiceProxy serviceProxy = new OrganizationServiceProxy(OrganizationUri, HomeRealmUri, Credentials, null))
{
    try
    {
        serviceProxy.EnableProxyTypes();
        request = new CrmUtilities.RetrieveEntityRequest();
        request.LogicalName=entityName;
        request.EntityFilters = EntityFilters.Entity;
        request.RequestName = requestName;

        //Execute Request
        retrieveEntityResponse =   (CrmUtilities.RetrieveEntityResponse)serviceProxy.Execute(request);
    }

    catch (System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapException ex)
    {
        throw ex;
    }

    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw ex;
    }
}
```

It says that ***MetadataId*** which is a required field is missing.The exception thrown is ***OrganizationServiceFault was caught //Required field 'MetadataId' is missing.***
How do i create a metadataId for this custom object in this case?

Comment: I wouldn't think this is possible since the CRM server has no idea what your RetrieveEntityRequest class is.  Did you see an example of this some where or is this just your best idea?

Answer (score 1):

Check out the [MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xrm.sdk.organizationrequest_members.aspx) for `OrganizationRequest`. One of the properties is `Parameters`, which is a collection of all the data needed for a request to work.

Your getter and setter should set (or retrieve) the value from that collection. You can't just create a private field and expect it to work. ;)

For the record - all the other request classes available in CRM SDK follow the same pattern - they derive from `OrganizationRequest` and the extra properties are just shortcuts to manipulate the required `Parameters`.

Answer (score 0):

Just guessing based on the exception your getting, because I don't know crm2011. But the exception is saying that the field is missing, what you have is a property. Whilst the difference may seem trivial there is a big difference when using reflection.

What you might need to do is:

```
public Guid MetadataId;
```

And remove your property.

Comment: i have done that already and the error was there even after that.